# Calculation of Average of distinct values

Tags: sql-server

I have date in below format:

[image]

Now, I am want to display latest Post Date of each Account No, its corresponding amount, average of Amount of all previous dates including the latest date but the hack is I need to display latest Post Date based on ShareID.

I need the Amount of minimum ShareID and while taking average I have to omit amount of duplicate/same date of max(Postdate).

I need the data in below format:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Also, consider not posting data in image format.  Table creation and insert statements are a great way to present sample data.

Comment: "latest Post Date based on ShareID" makes no sense - especially when your goal is a single row (as best I can guess) per account. Rather it seems you simply want the row with the maximum post date value along with some aggregation of other rows. And this doesn't seem much different from your previous question as regards to calculating an average (or sum in your previous question).

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
WITH
T1 AS
(
SELECT AccountNo, FundNo, MAX(PostDate) AS LastPostDate
FROM   MyTable
GROUP  BY AccountNo, FundNo,
),
T2 AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT AccountNo, FundNo, Amount
FROM   MyTable
)
SELECT T1.AccountNo, T1.FundNo, T1.LastPostDate, T.PostDate, AVG(T2.Amount)
FROM   T1
       JOIN T2 ON T1.AccountNo  = T2.AccountNo
       JOIN MyTable AS T ON T.AccountNo = T1.AccountNo AND T.PostDate,  = T1.LastPostDate
```

Post the DDL of your table and an example under a INSERT SQL statements to help us sto give a correct solution please.